# Jupyter notebook version

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, version

Here is my problem: I am currently using Jupyter notebook with my conda environment.

I wanted to update it to the latest version (6.0.3 atm) to have access to the NotebookApp.use_redirect_file tag in the config file (because Jupyter doesn't want to open the URL).

When I type jupyter notebook --version it shows 5.7.8 but when I type conda list, notebook is 6.0.3.

I have tried to uninstall and install anaconda again but it didn't fix it. I don't have other ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I just realised my problem is not what I thought. I just need to use anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook instead of the actual notebook. Maybe it's a problem with the PATH or I need to create an alias. I'm not really got with these things. If someone could tell me what to put in my .bashrc or provide me an other solution, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a photo for you and you can update or install a specific version of Jupyter Notebook using your Anaconda Navigator screen by settings button on Jupyter Notebook card.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w7vR.png

To access Anaconda Navigator:

**1st Step** 
Download Anaconda Distribution from [link](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)

**2nd Step**
Follow installation instructions from [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/) and install Anaconda Distribution

**3rd Step** 
Run Anaconda Navigator and you will see the Jupyter Notebook card on the main screen that I added in the answer.

Best of luck!

Comment: Can you add instructions for navigating to Anaconda Navigator screen?

Comment: Sure @stever, **1st Step** Download Anaconda Distribution from [link](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)  **2nd Step** Follow installation instructions from [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/) and install Anaconda Distribution **3rd Step** Run Anaconda Navigator and you will see the Jupyter Notebook card on the main screen that I added in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I've tried doing what you said. The version shown in the navigator was the correct one (6+) but my problem hasn't change. When I type jupyter-notebook --version it is still the wrong one so I can't use the --generate-config for the version that I want to use.

Comment: Please try first **pip install pip --upgrade** and then **conda upgrade notebook** in Anaconda Prompt

Comment: pip was upgraded and conda was already up to date but nothing changed :/

Comment: You may have multiple notebook installations and wrong or misleading paths may cause unexpected execution problems in the future, you can try to uninstall and remove everything related Anaconda including folders in your user folders or you can use a software for a complete uninstall. Then you can download and install latest version. Good luck!

Comment: I uninstalled Anaconda again an tried running jupyter-notebook again before installing a new version. It still runs. Now I have removed it also with pip but the version is still there. How can I get rid of it? If I install conda again it won't change anything.

Comment: Type `pip install pip-autoremove` and `pip-autoremove jupyter -y`. Then check what still installed there with  `conda list `. If you still have installations, type  `pip3 uninstall jupyter `, `pip3 uninstall jupyter_core `, `pip3 uninstall jupyter-client `, `pip3 uninstall jupyter-console `, `pip3 uninstall notebook `, `pip3 uninstall qtconsole `, `pip3 uninstall nbconvert `, `pip3 uninstall nbformat `

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I fixed my problem,
It seems that the problem was due to anaconda using the wrong version of Python. So the Jupyter version that I wanted was installed but Anaconda couln't use it. Now everything is working.